# Question about attachment upload and download

Tags: corda

First I have read the doc from corda about using attachment. However I still have question about the process of uploading and downloading attachment.

My task was to write a simple cordapp for transferring file from NodeA to NodeB. After uploading a zip file from NodeA shell, I received a hash and then included this in the transaction. The flow was successful. However, in NodeB, I could not get the file back. Then I tried to get the file back from NodeA using that hash. However, the shell returned error message and said invalidInputSteam.

But then when I ran cordaftp (https://github.com/corda/cordaftp) and tried to upload a file and download this from the same shell, the shell correctly asked the path for storage. I had read various posts and knew that I need to include extra codes for successfully downloading. But I have no idea which file I should amend and what code I should write. Hope someone can help me solve my problem as I already spent days on reading previous posts and doc.

Here below is the flow part:

```
@InitiatingFlow
@StartableByRPC
class FileInitiateFlow(
    val receiver: Party,
    val comment: String,
    val hash: SecureHash.SHA256) : FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>() {
    companion object {
    object GENERATING_TRANSACTION : Step("Generating transaction")
    object VERIFYING_TRANSACTION : Step("Verifying contract constraints.")
    object SIGNING_TRANSACTION : Step("Signing transaction with sender private key.")
    object GATHERING_SIGS : Step("Gathering the receiver's signature."){
        override fun childProgressTracker() = CollectSignaturesFlow.tracker()
    }

    object FINALISING_TRANSACTION : Step("Obtaining notary signature and recording transaction.") {
        override fun childProgressTracker() = FinalityFlow.tracker()
    }

    fun tracker() = ProgressTracker(
            GENERATING_TRANSACTION,
            VERIFYING_TRANSACTION,
            SIGNING_TRANSACTION,
            GATHERING_SIGS,
            FINALISING_TRANSACTION
    )
}

override val progressTracker = tracker()


@Suspendable
override fun call(): SignedTransaction {
    // Obtain a reference to the notary we want to use.
    val notary = serviceHub.networkMapCache.notaryIdentities[0]
    val sender = serviceHub.myInfo.legalIdentities.first()
    // Stage 1.
    progressTracker.currentStep = GENERATING_TRANSACTION
    // Generate an unsigned transaction.
    val fileState = FileState(sender, receiver,comment)
    val txCommand = Command(RoamingContract.Commands.FileInitiate(), fileState.participants.map { it.owningKey })
    val txBuilder = TransactionBuilder(notary)
            .addOutputState(fileState, ID)
            .addCommand(txCommand)
            .addAttachment(hash)

    // Stage 2.
    progressTracker.currentStep = VERIFYING_TRANSACTION
    // Verify that the transaction is valid.
    txBuilder.verify(serviceHub)

    // Stage 3.
    progressTracker.currentStep = SIGNING_TRANSACTION
    // Sign the transaction.
    val partSignedTx = serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(txBuilder)

    // Stage 4.
    progressTracker.currentStep = GATHERING_SIGS
    // Send the state to the counterparty, and receive it back with their signature.
    val otherPartyFlow = initiateFlow(receiver)
    val fullySignedTx = subFlow(CollectSignaturesFlow(partSignedTx, setOf(otherPartyFlow), GATHERING_SIGS.childProgressTracker()))

    // Stage 5.
    progressTracker.currentStep = FINALISING_TRANSACTION
    // Notarise and record the transaction in both parties' vaults.
    return subFlow(FinalityFlow(fullySignedTx, FINALISING_TRANSACTION.childProgressTracker()))
}
}

@InitiatedBy(FileInitiateFlow::class)
class FileInitiateRespond(val senderFlow: FlowSession) :         FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>() {
@Suspendable
override fun call(): SignedTransaction{
    val signedTransactionFlow = object : SignTransactionFlow(senderFlow) {
        override fun checkTransaction(stx: SignedTransaction) = requireThat {
            val output = stx.tx.outputs.single().data
            "This must be an File State" using (output is FileState)
        }
    }
    return subFlow(signedTransactionFlow)
}
}
```

So I first run uploadAttachment for uploading the zip file, I got the hash and then start the flow, with hash as input. The flow was succeeded, but in receiver's side, I could not get the hash key for the uploaded file from checking existing state.

Comment: can u share ur code !! The code is pretty straight forward for uploading and downloading

Comment: @manish,hi I already post my code for the flow part

Comment: Code seems ok to me .If you can share the git hub project i can debug

Comment: @manish, here is the github link ,https://github.com/wyfok/Roaming_Project.git 
thanks for help

Comment: @hkgyyf What command are you running to download the attachment? What error do you get?

Comment: @Joel 
please find the attached pic for your reference 
[https://i.imgur.com/LvSkPn4.png]

Answer (score 0):

Attachment hashes of instances of `SecureHash`. There is a bug in Corda 3.2/3.3 whereby the shell cannot convert strings into `SecureHash` objects.

The fix is here: https://github.com/corda/corda/pull/3248 and will be available in Corda 4.

Comment: However, if I ran cordaftp (https://github.com/corda/cordaftp) I could download the attachment using hash in the sender shell. Is it possible to modify  Kotlin CorDapp Template if I also want to do so in shell?

Comment: Here is the screenshot for uploading and downloading attachment using cordaftp 
https://i.imgur.com/nrl9ecO.jpg

Comment: Realised that cordaftp uses corda 3.0 to build. Is it possible to download corda 3.0 kotlin template now?